# css :hover not working after jquery load();

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm loading elements into a div using the load() function. But then the :hover effect in css does no longer work for does elements.

it's a dynamic menu, like this:

```
<div id='main-menu'>
<ul>
<li class='click-me hover-me'></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id='alternative-menu'>
</div>
```

then i load a new menu into the alternative menu and hide the old one in js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.click-me', function(){

    $('#alternative-menu').load('newmenu.php', function(){$('#main-menu').hide();});
});
```

the new menu's html code looks like this:

```
echo "
    <ul>
    <li class='click-me hover-me'></li>
    </ul>";
```

in my css i have:

```
.hover-me{
font-size:12px;
}

.hover-me:hover{
background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Could be that the CSS isn't being applied to the newly loaded menu. Could you have both menus in separate DIVs and then show/hide each DIV based on your criteria?

Comment: @Ryan, i already had that, i'm sorry - i updated my question

Comment: @BenGreene maybe there is an other hover effect for `alternative-menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to add the proper CSS class using jQuery after it's been loaded.

Maybe something like:

```
$('#alternative-menu').load('newmenu.php', function() {
    $('#main-menu').hide();
}).children("li").addClass("hover-me");
```